# Quantum darwinism or just entropy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, decoherence

[Quantum darwinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Darwinism) is a hypothesis that some quantum states are more robust in that they are less likely to decohere under interactions with the environment. These states are "fittest" and eventually win and get copied around, such that everyone agrees that there is a rock right there.

However, entropy provides an alternative way in which macroscopic systems stabilize. Consider a room with nitrogen and oxygen in it. After a while of interacting with the environment, all states of the [gas in a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_in_a_box) are equally likely. States with equal mixtures everywhere are much more likely than states with large patches of oxygen-depleted regions. There is no "favoring" of individual states over others, just a vast numerical majority of states that look the same.

Is quantum darwinism a separate process for creating our classical world?